# Plotting a general ZigZag curve with possible threshold value

Tags: plotting, visualization, peak-detection

I want to use zigzag curve to describe the trend of simple data. here is a list as

```
lstPrices={4.36,4.32,4.2,4.2,4.22,4.12,4.28,4.29,4.29,4.31,4.25,4.35,4.59,4.68,4.61,4.59,5.05,4.95,5.09,5.11,4.99,4.96,5.11,5.37,5.6,5.38,5.42,5.36,4.9,4.92,4.98,4.89,4.99,4.8,4.79,4.62,4.65,4.7,4.68,4.7,4.81,4.84,4.77,4.85,4.78,4.69,4.71,4.66,4.69,4.78,4.78,4.81,4.85,4.78,5.1,5.29,5.19,5.28,5.22,5.18,5.07,5.08,5.09,5.07,5.1,5.05,5.05,5.13,5.1,5.09,5.21,5.24,5.26,5.35,5.19,5.24,5.09,5.18,5.19,5.18,5.13,5.15,5.06,5.09,5.08,5.01,4.99,4.99,4.94,4.98,4.92,4.87,4.91,4.91,4.92,4.95,4.9,4.93,4.99,5.04,4.98,5.17,5.07,5.08,5.14,5.17,5.08,5.53,5.57,5.49,5.47,5.64,5.48,5.47,5.31,5.36,5.35,5.31,5.37,5.35};
```

and I give new definition of `FindPeaks` and the related.

```
JFindPeaks[list_?ListQ] := MapAt[Round, FindPeaks[list] // N, {All, 1}]
JFindValleys[list_?ListQ] := Module[{x, y}, Map[({x, y} = #; {x, -y}) &, JFindPeaks[-list]]]
JFindExtremes[list_?ListQ] := Sort[JFindPeaks[list]~Join~JFindValleys[list]]
```

then some lists are computed as

```
peaks = JFindPeaks[lstPrices];
valls = JFindValleys[lstPrices];
extrs = JFindExtremes[lstPrices];
```

and two plots too,

```
p1 = ListLinePlot[lstPrices,
   Epilog -> {
     {Red, PointSize[0.015], Point[peaks]},
     {Blue, PointSize[0.015], Point[valls]}},
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Dotted]
   ];
p2 = Graphics@Line@extrs;
```

finnally, the target plot comes out.

```
Show[p1, p2,
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
 Frame -> True,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dotted],
 ImageSize -> Large
 ]
```

It's like this,

[image]

but the most I want to get could be like the following one or the other similarly, or these sub-peaks-valleys should be ellminated on the plot.

[image]

so how to realize it? Maybe a `threshold` value  is necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the Gaussian blurring scale $\sigma$ in `FindPeaks` to do that:

```
ClearAll[JFindPeaks];

sigma = 5;
JFindPeaks[list_List] := FindPeaks[list, sigma]
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks more!

Comment: How to compute the `sigma` value according to `increase` or `decrease` `range` by the target plot adjacent peak-valley points? e.x. If range = 0.20(*20%*), then `sigma = ?`, is this poissible ?

Comment: @Jerry `sigma` is a blurring parameter. It is related to the width of small peaks which you want to ignore.
If you want to ignore small peaks which are narrower than 20% of your full range (120 units) you may take
sigma about `0.20 * 120 / 2`.